# ResNeSt problem:load_state_dict_from_url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check_hash'

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

I have run the ResNeSt model in the fastai, but I got a problem.

`learn = fastai.vision.cnn_learner(data, resnest50(pretrained=True), metrics=[accuracy])`

And the Error is here:

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cff6dd69b503> in <module>
----> 1 learn = fastai.vision.cnn_learner(data, resnest50(pretrained=True), metrics=[accuracy])

F:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\resnest\torch\resnest.py in resnest50(pretrained, root, **kwargs)
     38     if pretrained:
     39         model.load_state_dict(torch.hub.load_state_dict_from_url(
---> 40             resnest_model_urls['resnest50'], progress=True, check_hash=True))
     41     return model
     42 

TypeError: load_state_dict_from_url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check_hash'```

Thanks for your help!
````

Answer (score 1):

We have recently updated the model URL, please install the newest version of ResNeSt https://github.com/zhanghang1989/ResNeSt

```
pip install resnest --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have checked my pytorch source code, and I find the code of `load_state_dict_from_url()` in my PC is different from the official code. I think it is a version problem. I don't konw if I need upgrade my pytorch version. If my cuda will not compatible with the new torch?